# Run my app ruby on local bash ubuntu on windows

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this answer after try to run my app in ruby on mi bash ubuntu on windows 10

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.1.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 4.1.0)', in any of
the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "coffee-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)

```
social-share-button (~> 0.1.6) was resolved to 0.1.10, which depends on
  coffee-rails
```

¿What do you recommend me?

Comment: Are you really sure you need a specific version of Rails? If so, try `gem install bundler -v 1.17.3`. If not, remove the `= 4.1.0` from your Gemfile and try again.

Comment: Thanks for comment, i tried with both recomendations. Installed the bundler -v 1.17.3 and i removed the version of rails, so my gemfile right now is the next: